# Displaying Records with route53 using .net

Tags: amazon-route53

Before I begin I do want to mention this is my first time doing this so forgive any errors I might do. I am currently learning how to use route53 using .net and I am currently stuck on getting it to post records in a field. I have the correct Accesskey,Secretkey and hostedzone id.

iv tested pulling up the name of the hosted zone aswell as getting it to display the number of records. but when i try to get it to actually post the values it displays: "Amazon.Route53.Model.ListResourceRecordSetsResponse". I'm sure the answer is right there in front of me but in the API for route53 there isnt really any guidelines to showing records. it shows you how to create records but not simply viewing them.

Here is what I have:

```
route53Client.ListResourceRecordSets(new ListResourceRecordSetsRequest
                {
                    HostedZoneId = "HostedZoneId here",
                    MaxItems = "1"

                });
```

I'm assuming that I am not including enough information for it to properly pull the records. I can pull them up through the AWS CLI so I know I have what i need to see them. just stuck on this part. any help would be great.

Here is the link to the API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html

Comment: From the information you have posted it sounds likely that you are successfully getting a response back from Route53 -- you should assign that response to variable and then "do something" with it -- at least breakpoint in the debugger to allow you to examine what is in the `ListResourceRecordSetResponse` that you get back.  Look at the following article for some examples of C# .Net code working against Route 53. https://www.derpturkey.com/amazon-route53-c-examples-reading-records/

Answer (score 0):

Process `ListResourceRecordSetResponse` like this:

```
var result = client.ListResourceRecordSets(
            {
                HostedZoneId = "HostedZoneId here",
                MaxItems = "1"
            });

foreach (var recordSet in result.ListResourceRecordSetsResult.ResourceRecordSets)
{
    // ResourceRecordSet
    foreach(var resourceRecord in recordSet.ResourceRecords)
    {
        // ResourceRecord
        Console.WriteLine(resourceRecord.Value);
    }
}
```

[ListResourceRecordSetsResponse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Route53/TListResourceRecordSetsResponse.html)

[ResourceRecordSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Route53/TResourceRecordSet.html)

[ResourceRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Route53/TResourceRecord.html)